# Short code to extract fitted value from tbl_df objects

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have a data set containing groups of data and I performed regression on on each group of data. I used dplyr to do the regression and get a tbl_df object with all results. Then I want to extract fitted value vector for each group of regression and put them in a data frame. I used to use summarise() to extract relevant information conveniently. But it only works for scalars. Here is some sample code with lapply I used to extract the information and I feel it kind of cumbersome:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df1 = data.frame(type1 = c(rep('a',5),rep('b',5)),
             x = 1:10,
             y = 11:20)

df1 %>% 
 group_by(type1) %>% 
do(model = lm(y~x,.)) -> model1

names(model1$model) = model1$type1

lapply(model1$model,function(mod) mod$fit) %>% 
  melt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(broom)
model1 %>% augment(model)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 10
> # Groups:   type1 [2]
>     type1     y     x .fitted      .se.fit        .resid  .hat       .sigma      .cooksd   .std.resid
>    <fctr> <int> <int>   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
>  1      a    11     1      11 2.482534e-16  3.567051e-19   0.6 3.925229e-16 2.322633e-06  0.001759785
>  2      a    12     2      12 1.755417e-16  3.026750e-16   0.3 2.977199e-16 2.730293e-01  1.128776594
>  3      a    13     3      13 1.433292e-16 -3.857170e-16   0.2 2.471607e-16 2.263176e-01 -1.345563357
>  4      a    14     4      14 1.755417e-16 -1.380180e-16   0.3 3.747906e-16 5.677113e-02 -0.514715401
>  5      a    15     5      15 2.482534e-16  2.207032e-16   0.6 3.052655e-16 8.891591e-01  1.088827560
>  6      b    16     6      16 1.709167e-15 -2.416065e-15   0.6 8.008132e-17 2.248024e+00 -1.731290167
>  7      b    17     7      17 1.208563e-15  2.359219e-15   0.3 1.824137e-15 3.499565e-01  1.277939838
>  8      b    18     8      18 9.867878e-16  1.265324e-15   0.2 2.510473e-15 5.138141e-02  0.641132787
>  9      b    19     9      19 1.208563e-15  5.595623e-17   0.3 2.702016e-15 1.968677e-04  0.030310330
> 10      b    20    10      20 1.709167e-15 -1.264434e-15   0.6 2.303179e-15 6.157097e-01 -0.906060815
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Broom is really handy!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tidyverse` package, which contains `dplyr`, `purrr`, `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Use `nest` and `map`

```
df1 %>% 
 group_by(type1) %>%
 nest() %>%
 mutate(data = map(data, ~lm(y~x,.x)$fit)) %>%     # combined lm with $fit
 unnest()
```

#### Output

```
    type1  data
 1      a    11
 2      a    12
 3      a    13
 4      a    14
 5      a    15
 6      b    16
 # etc
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `modelr` together with `tidyverse`. The `add_predictions` function is handy. Here is an example.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)

# Create example data frame
df1 = data.frame(type1 = c(rep('a',5),rep('b',5)),
                 x = 1:10,
                 y = 11:20)

# Created nested data frame
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(type1) %>% 
  nest()

# A function to fit lm model to y ~ x
lm_model <- function(df) {
  lm(y ~ x, data = df)
}

# Fit model
df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, lm_model))

# Add prediction
df4 <- df3 %>%
  mutate(Pred = map2(data, model, add_predictions))

# Unnest the data frame
df5 <- df4 %>% unnest(Pred)

df5
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    type1     x     y  pred
   <fctr> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1      a     1    11    11
 2      a     2    12    12
 3      a     3    13    13
 4      a     4    14    14
 5      a     5    15    15
 6      b     6    16    16
 7      b     7    17    17
 8      b     8    18    18
 9      b     9    19    19
10      b    10    20    20
```

Comment: Cool! I haven't made an effort to learn `modelr` yet; I've been curious what it does that `broom` doesn't.

Comment: @Brian Thanks! I like your approach using `broom`. Actually, I just started to learn how to use `modelr` and I am not familiar with `broom`. But I am sure both of them are useful for some tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like provide a slick answer using data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
data.table %>%  
.[,
  .(x,
    y,
    fit = lm(y~x)$fit),
  by = type1]
```